# Private messaging system Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've been trying to set up a basic private messaging system in Django using the generic CreateView.

I am currently having trouble with the "Receiver"/"To" field in my form.  I tried to make it so it was a drop down field with the options being followers of the logged-in user.

Currently, the field is populating with the correct usernames (in this case, "testuser1") but it is throwing an error saying this field needs to be populated with an instance of the User object.

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'testuser1'": "Message.reciever" must be a "User" instance.
```

Is there a way to have the form pass in the object of the username that is selected?

Model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sender")
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reciever")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="-")
    content = models.TextField()
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

User Relationships Model:

```
class UserRelationships(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
    following_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followers")

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**UPDATED** Form:

```
class MessageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['sender', 'reciever', 'subject', 'content']
        widgets = {'sender': forms.HiddenInput()}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        follower_objects = kwargs.pop('follower_objects')
        super(MessageCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['reciever'] = RecieverModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(username__in=follower_objects))
```

View:

```
class MessageCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Message
    template_name = 'message/compose.html'
    form_class = MessageCreateForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['sender'] = self.request.user
        return initial

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        user = self.request.user
        followers = user.followers.values_list('user_id', flat=True)
        follower_objects = []
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        kwargs['follower_objects'] = follower_objects 
        for id in followers:
            follower = User.objects.get(id=id)
            follower_objects.append(follower)
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `forms.ModelChoiceField` instead of `forms.ChoiceField`

> [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) (model) > ModelChoiceField (form) - Default widget: Select

[ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) has attribute [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset).

You can filter field `reciever.queryset` directly in `MessageCreateForm.__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(MessageCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['reciever'].queryset = user.followers
```

**UPDATE:**

You can set a custom `ModelChoiceField` that will return any label you want ([more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.iterator)).

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class RecieverModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.username
```

or

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
    self.fields['reciever'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "%s" % obj.username
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like this is working.  Is there a way to get the selection box to still display the username of the user (vs. the model name/string representation)?

Comment: @tsmith41094, I've updated my answer with an example of custom labels.

Comment: this works perfectly thank you! I only had to make one other edit to my form (updated above) because the field was supplying an instance of the `UserRelationships` model when it required a `User` instance.  Probably not the most elegant solution but seems to be working.